# How to get administrative privilege to open a directory in C drive of Windows vista/7 in java

Tags: java, user-permissions

I tried to open a directory present in c drive in java code, but failed. It throws an exception as Access denied. I am using windows 7. How can I open that directory. Any suggestions.

Comment: Please *don't* give us any code that you're executing or mention the directory that you're trying to open or post a copy of the error message that you got. All of that would make it *far* to easy to answer the question and we rather like the challenge.

Comment: @ Joachim Sauer: I created a folder named test in c drive and i tried to access the files inside it.

Answer (score 1):

This is a UAC issue I think.
UAC (User Access Control) is a new Microsoft Windows system integrated since Windows Vista and tries to resemble the Linux "sudo" command.
Microsoft finally realized that having ALL processes running with Administrative privileges is a security hazard and added this feature.
As a Win7 user you probably have noticed that when you try to install something you get a prompt asking you if you would allow the process to run at Admin level. That's UAC for you.

The problem is that there is no way to ELEVATE a running process to Admin level, and the software must be ran at Admin level from the very start (right-click -> Run As Administrator).
It is also possible to go to the program executables' properties and set it to require Administrative privileges to run.

If you only need a small operation done in Elevated mode you could spawn a new process with Elevation to do a small task for you. Look at the Java API/Google to find how to do that.